# Thumbnail scale when share link in Facebook mobile

Tags: facebook, share, thumbnails, meta-tags, preview

I'm sharing link in Facebook with thumbnail, i try to test:

- In debugger: OK
  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibxi4.png)
- In desktop: OK
  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDpoM.png)

## - **In mobile: Thumbnail scale image**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/R43nO.png)

I used og:image in head with dimension: 1200x360

```
<meta property="og:title" content="This is title">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Test">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://picsum.photos/id/237/1200/630">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
```

I can't find any bug why thumbnail in mobile is scaled